# dask: groupby on bag shows unexpected behavior

Tags: python, dask

I'm going through the dask tutorial at https://tutorial.dask.org/02_bag.html and am surprised by the behavior of groupby + starmap on a bag:

> [image: Screenshot Dask Tutorial]

Why are there multiple entries with the same key in the first cell's result?
The author did not seem to expect that either: They say the 2nd cell produces the same result. It doesn't.

Did something change in the definition of groupby?
If this behavior is expected (just not by me), is it documented somewhere?
I tried and failed to reproduce this with a bag created from a sequence.

Comment: Additional information: The behavior disappeared when I ran the code against a dask cluster created in a separate process (via dask jupyterlab extension)

Comment: I'm a bit surprised not to see any response to this. (It's not a complaint, of course. Just surprise.) Maybe this is because my first comment may look like the problem disappeared. That's not what I wanted to say. It's even stranger to see these different behaviors, I think.